# Is it possible to find such a computable function $f(n)$, there doesn't exist a limit point for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)}{2n} ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, examples-counterexamples, computability

Let, $a_n=\left\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots, a_{n\to\infty}\right\}$ be a computable infinite sequence, or $f(n)=\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a computable function, where $i≥1, ∀ a_i\in\left\{0,1,2\right\}$.

> We have $$0≤\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{2n}≤1$$

For example:

Let, $$a_n=\left\{0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2\cdots \cdots\cdots\right\}$$ or $$f(n)=n+2-3 \left \lfloor {\frac{n+2}{3}}\right \rfloor$$

Then, we get

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_n=\left \lfloor{\frac{n - 2}{3}}\right\rfloor + 2 \left(\left\lfloor{\frac n3}\right\rfloor + 1 \right) + 1$$

So, we have

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_n}{2n}=\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{n - 2}{3}}\right\rfloor + 2 \left(\left\lfloor{\frac n3}\right\rfloor + 1 \right) + 1}{2n}=\frac 12$$

This  result imply, if $f(n)=n+2-3 \left \lfloor {\frac{n+2}{3}}\right \rfloor$ there exist a stationary limit point for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)}{2n}$, which equals to $\frac 12.$

And here is my question:

> If the function $f(k)$ is computable, is there always a limit point for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)}{2n}$ or is it possible to find such a computable function $f(n)$, there doesn't exist a limit point for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)}{2n}$ ?

I mean, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{sup} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)}{2n}≠\lim_{n\to\infty} \text{inf}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)}{2n}$$

Comment: What do you mean by stationary limit point?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt there is not stationary limit point for : $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {(-1)^n}{2}=\left\{-\frac 12 , \frac 12\right\}$

Comment: I assume you consider $\infty$ as a limit point as well?

Comment: @rtybase yes you are right.

Comment: Every sequence has a limit point if you include $\infty$, due to the $\limsup$ always existing in $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I include only $\lim \text {sup}=\lim \text {inf}$

Comment: It's not clear as to what you are saying.

Comment: I think @Elvin means *unique* limit point?

Comment: Ah my bad. ._. well my answer still applies.

Comment: @Elvin try $f(n)=(-1)^n \cdot n$

Comment: I think you didn't read a question correct :(

Comment: Consider, for example, $g(n)=(-1)^n$. Then you have $f(n)=n(-1)^n-(n-1)(-1)^{n-1}=(2n-1)(-1)^n$ as a counterexample, from my answer. This is essentially @rtybase's example.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, I believe that if you have $(-1)^n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)(-1)^k$ then this is enough.

Comment: Perhaps you should emphasize the point that $a_i\in\{0,1,2\}$. This is only mentioned once, and is not included in the question "If the function $f(k)$ is computable...", so it is very easy to pass over.

Comment: You simply mean that a limit doesn't exist. As I mentioned in my comment under your previous question. Which you denied just to close that question and open this question with the same content

Comment: You should also link related questions: [Is there such an infinite sequence, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_n}{2n}=\text{ exact form constant}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3257245)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt These questions are different.

Comment: They aren't related whatsoever? Because it seems to me that these are very similar questions, in fact.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes, you are right. Only similar. Not the same.

Comment: Then why not link it? It gives readers an understanding of where this question may've come from and why you might be asking this, as well as more information that can help us answer the question.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it has been very difficult to answer, given the amount of things you've asked and the little you have clarified. The fact that most of the confusion had to be cleared up by someone else should speak for itself.

Comment: Please edit the question to define what you mean by "stationary limit point".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is mine.  $f(k) = 0$ if $k$ has an even number of digits, and $f(k) = 1$ if $k$ has an odd number of digits.

So:
$f(k) = 1$ for $k$ from $1$ to $9$, since $k$ has $1$ digit and $1$ is odd.
$f(k) = 0$ for $k$ from $10$ to $99$, since $k$ has $2$ digits and $2$ is even.
$f(k) = 1$ for $k$ from $100$ to $999$, since $k$ has $3$ digits and $3$ is odd.
$f(k) = 0$ for $k$ from $1000$ to $9999$, since $k$ has $4$ digits and $4$ is even.

---

Now let's do some computations for special values of $n$.  First consider  $n = 10^z-1$ with $z$ even.  Then
$$
f(k) = 0, \quad 10^{z-1} \le k < 10^z,
\\
f(k) \le 1, \quad 1 \le k < 10^{z-1}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \le 10^{z-1} = \frac{n}{10}
\\
\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \le \frac{1}{20} .
$$
From this we conclude 
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \le \frac{1}{20}
$$

Next consider  $n = 10^z-1$ with $z$ odd.  Then
$$
f(k) = 1, \quad 10^{z-1} \le k < 10^z,
\\
f(k) \ge 0, \quad 1 \le k < 10^{z-1}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \ge 10^z - 10^{z-1} = \frac{9 n}{10}
\\
\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \ge \frac{9}{20} .
$$
From this we conclude 
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \ge \frac{9}{20}
$$
Finally,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)\qquad\text{does not exist.}
$$

Comment: (+1) Please, can you add more details?

Comment: I need to write me a your infinite sequence/function the first 10 term.. Thank you.

Comment: The first $10$ terms are: $1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}0,&\frac1n\sum_{k\le n}a_k>\frac32\lor\left(\frac1n\sum_{k\le n}a_k>\frac12\land a_n=0\right)\\2,&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

This gives us a computable sequence of $0$'s and $2$'s that have both $\frac14$ and $\frac34$ as limit points, or more simply, we have $a_n<\frac14$ for infinitely many $n$ and $a_n>\frac34$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: The limit point can not big from $1$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what "can not big" means.

Comment: $$0≤\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)}{2n}≤1$$

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at $\frac1n\sum a_k$. If you divide this by $2$, it is between your bounds.

Comment: Thank you +1 $. $